# Rigorous proof that any linear map between vector spaces can be represented by a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I searching the internet in hope of finding a proof. However, most of what I have seen this relationship is defined informally and/or gloss off this. Would you kindly point me in the direction of a resource that prove this or give me a hint of how to construct a proof. **Please** don't not deny me the opportunity of understanding the proof or proving it myself!

Comment: "I searching the internet in hope of finding a proof. " You could also use *any* book on linear algebra. Or your mind. "I know that this is the only possible between finite vector spaces. " No. The (column-finite) matrix representation works for all linear maps between vector spaces with a given basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start from the definition of $f$ a linear map between $E$ and $F$. A linear map has the following properties:

$f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}) = f(\mathbf{x})+f(\mathbf{y})$ (additivity)

$f(\alpha \mathbf{x}) = \alpha f(\mathbf{x})$ (homogeneity of degree $1$)

As a result, you can define $f$ from its values $f(e_i)$ over any base $e_i$. Express $f(e_i)$ into a base of $F$ and you've got the matrix.

Answer (score 2):

For every linear map there is the possibility of finding its matrix. This is done, for example, by using this

**Theorem**:
Let V and W be two K - vector spaces with $\mathcal{A} = (v_1,...,v_n)$ a basis of V and $\mathcal{B} = (w_1,...,w_n)$ a basis of W. Then to every linear map $F:V\to W$ there is a unique matrix $A=(a_{ij}) \in M \space (m \space x \space n, K) $ such that

$$F(v_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}w_i \space \space \space for \space j=1,...,n,$$

and the obtained map

$$M_B^A:Hom(V,W) \to M \space (m \space x \space n, K)$$ 
$$F\mapsto M_B^A(F),$$

is an Isomorphism between K - vector spaces. In particular:

$$M_B^A(F+G)=M_B^A(F) + M_B^A(G)$$

and

$$M_B^A(\lambda F) = \lambda M_B^A(F)$$

in poor words if you choose fix basis you can represent you map by a matrix. The notation $M_B^A(F)$ tells you that the matrix that you obtain with the coefficient $a_{ij}$ represent your linear map with respect to the basis $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$. (you could say that you "read" the vectors in basis $\mathcal{A}$ and you "write" them in basis $\mathcal{B}$.

This theorem is taken from the book: Gerd Fischer, *Lineare Algebra*, 17. Auflage. and at page 139 you can find the proof of the theorem.

If you search for an application of this problem that helps you understanding how one can actually obtain the matrix of a linear function I suggest you this pretty famous exercise:

> **Exercise**: Find the matrix of the linear application
>
> $$f:V\to V$$
>
> $$p(x)\mapsto \frac{\delta}{\delta x} p(x)$$
>
> where $V= \{p \in \mathbb{R}[X] | p = 0 \lor deg (p) \lt n\}$

as result you should obtain the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &... & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 &... & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 &... & 0 \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &... & n-1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &... & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: K being the dimension?

Comment: No, K-vectorspace means that you vectorspace, say V is in the field K